# netplan - conditional loading of config

Tags: netplan

I have a yaml for my ethernet connect and a yaml with various access points defined for my wifi.

I want to load the wifi yaml only if the ethernet connection is not available.

Comment: Netplan does not have that kind of granularity over conditional control to configure interfaces.  It can define optional interfaces, but not conditional like "if: other connection not available, configure wifi."

Comment: `optional: true`  under the ethernet device name is not good enough?

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for conditional loading  of configurations.  Instead, you might find that you can solve your problem either using metrics (so that traffic always prefers the ethernet device if present) or, if the ethernet and wifi are both on the same network, by using a bridge between the two interfaces with the ethernet device set as primary.